# NX Monorepo and emotion theme in libs

Tags: reactjs, emotion, nrwl-nx

We want to use `useTheme` from `@emotion/react` inside libs and inside our apps

we are useing:
-react-native-web
-nx monorepo
-react-native

This is our structure

```
 -apps
  --web (ReactJS)
  --mobile (React-native)
 -libs
  --shared-ui
    --components
    --theming
```

and when we want to use useTheme in app we have to declare Theme like that

```
import '@emotion/react';
import { ThemeType } from '@awesomeapp-frontend/ui';

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme extends ThemeType {}
}
```

and then put this into provider:

```
import { light } from '@awesomeapp-frontend/ui';

...
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={light}>
```

but this declaration works only for web app we can now use our definition of ThemeType

```
.... // type for theme
export type ThemeType = {
  colors: {
    primary: string;
    myOwnColor: string;
  };
};

.... // in component
const App = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  console.log('THEME IN COMPONENT: ', theme);

  return <div style={{ color: theme.colors.primary }}>Oi, I am web app</div>;
...
```

And questions is how can we use this type for `ThemeProvider` in lib folder
When i log out useTheme data are there

```
{
colors: {
 primary: 'red'
 myOwnColor: 'blue'
}
}
```

but typescrypt dont know it and complaining... How can i set up global type for emotin to be available also in lib folder?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, However, it seems like you are struggling to share types inside libs. So I suggest creating one more lib for types only and defining all types in this lib and using them inside other libs.

Like this,

- **common** (libs for types only)
- **api-common** (libs for API types, It will extend most types from the common lib)
- **ui-common** (libs for UI types, It will extend most types from the common lib)

Like I have an app with React and MongoDB and I have to share types, But the problem is on the API side the _id field type is ObjectId and string on the front end I have done something like this.

## Address.ts in common lib.

```
export class AddressWithoutIds {
    public city: string = '';
    public postalCode: string = '';
}
```

## Address.ts in api-common lib.

```
export class Address extends AddressWithoutIds {
    public _id: ObjectId;
}
```

## Address.ts in ui-common lib.

```
export class Address extends AddressWithoutIds {
    public _id: string;
}
```